# Receiving either WM_QueryEndSession or WM_WTSSESSIONCHANGE in WinPE10 in C#

Tags: c#, wndproc, winpe

My apologies if this question has been asked and already answered, I have spent the best part of three days experimenting with WndProc() in *WinPE (for Windows 10).*

How do I "Catch" Messages through WndProc() (or a Handler Routine) in *WinPE (Windows 10)?*

I have a custom application(written in C# .Net 4.5.2) that is launched by WinPEShl.exe, on boot of WinPE.  This is currently an Application that provides access to other applications to enable Windows deployment or Image Capture.

While this Application may not always be the current Windows Form, there a one or two routines that need to be completed before Windows PE has shutdown.  I would like this to happen on either the WM_QUERYENDSESSION/WM_ENDSESSION or WTS_SESSION_CHANGE notifications through the overriden WndProc() function.

Currently this is my WndProc() function:

```
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Listen for operating system messages.
        if (m.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        {
            Program.WriteLogFile(4, 1, "WM_QUERYENDSISSION: received. Return Bool=True");
        }
        if (m.Msg == WTS.WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE)
        {
            int wValue = m.WParam.ToInt32();
            if (wValue == WTS.WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF)
            {
                //Write my darn Log file!
                Program.WriteLogFile(4, 1, "WM_WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF: received. Return Bool=True");
            }
            if (wValue == WTS.WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT)
            {
                Program.WriteLogFile(4, 1, "WM_WTS_SESSION_DISCONNECT: received. Return Bool=True");
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Program.WriteLogFile() is a Log File writer (as it says!) that will be used to report that the system is shutting down.

From this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-apps) I am aware that as WinPE is a Stream lined version of Windows, with only a small number of API's being available for usage.  I have looked through both of the MinCore.lib sets for both Windows API Sets mentioned - resulting in nill success for finding any function in relation to the WndProc() holder function. I have evensearched OneCore.lib aswell.

I did however find the WTSRegiSessionNotifications() functions. Again even though they register fine in WinPE, my Shell App doesn't receive the messages if another application shuts down the system (such as Windows Setup on completion of the first phase).

Testing in Windows provides both results in the associated application log file.

Should I be using a hidden console app, to capture the CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT/CTRL-SHUTDOWN_EVENT, or should i be using a service (and have all log writing routed through it)?

Log files from Windows 10 (working as should be) and WinPE available on request.

Thanks for any and all help in this matter.

Kind regards

Richie

Comment: Not so sure why this is a problem, but the approach is certainly wrong.  The OS stops running when the user flips the power switch.  No nice notification for that, there is no power to keep your program going.  Code accordingly.

Comment: Please extrapolate further as to why the approach is wrong?

Comment: You are right, if the User hits the power button and the system is terminated, that is the users concern and not mine if the system bricks.

However, if one of my applications if the initiator of the System Shutdown/Reboot then My Custom App needs to tidy its open files up.  WInPE is in a Flat boot install on a USB drive, not as a RAMDISK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're not using the regular winforms form lifetime events. I'm guessing you're somewhat more used to C-oriented ways of doing things?

If you've built a `winpeshl.ini` that starts your program, and it's the only program listed (beyond `winpeinit.exe`), then when it shuts down, PE shuts down. This is true even if you spawn other applications from your main program (via System.Diagnostics.Process).

So, don't list a lot of programs in `winpeshl.ini`. Let your one-and-only main program start the rest.

FWIW, I've got a similar app...does image capture, deploy and periodic maintenance. We put our winPE in it's own partition and do a lot of active BCD management to make it boot when we want. I've closed off all the "normal" shutdown routes. Yes, I suppose a persistent user can circumvent...but if they're determined, so be it...but we haven't had an issue with that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  It's more used to Pascal!

I have tried using the lifetime events, nothing fires, unless in the full OS.  I set up a Windows Event monitor, while In WinPE10 - there were 3 application level event messages that I couldn't find out what they were.
The next process will be to look into the WinLogon events ( I have done this before but in Pascal, back in the early 2000's when building a Network Management Suite).

For know I will have to accept I can't intercept a shutdown event and look at the server messaging from within the build/deploy apps.